# Running python scripts from lighttpd - Firefox asking to save file

Tags: python, cgi, lighttpd

I am trying to run a simple Python script from my lighttpd server. The HTML code is:

```
<html>
<title>Interactive page</title>
<body>
    <form method=POST action="cgi-bin/cgi101.py">
        <P><B>Entery your name: </B>
        <P><input type=text name=user>
        <P><input type=submit>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print('Content type:text/html \n')
print('<title>Reply Page</title>')
if not 'user' in form:
    print('<h1>who are you</h1>')
else:
    print(cgi.escape(form['user'].value))
```

So my question is, am I able to load the HTML page and then I click on Submit Query? Firefox is asking "You have chosen to open cgi101.py" from localhost and asking what should Firefox do with this file and whether I want to save it. Shouldn't it just open in Firefox and run the Python script rather than asking me to save the Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have the same problem yesterday when I'm learning the Programing Python book.I find the answer after that is you loss an important step.That is you have lost a webserver.py file which implements an HTTP web server in Python that knows how to run server-side CGI scripts coded in Python; serves files and scripts from current working dir.Here is the code:

```
`import os,sys
from http.server import HTTPServer,CGIHTTPRequestHandler

webdir = '.'
port = 80

os.chdir(webdir)
srvraddr = ("",port)
srvrobj = HTTPServer(srvraddr,CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()`
```

you can try it again!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
add chmod +x file name to make it executable.